# Read data from excel and ignore the blank lines in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This could be silly but I need to import some data from excel in python where the data is printed somewhere in the worksheet (not starting at A1 location).

```
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...  
... ... ... ... ... Timestamp  a   b   c   d 
... ... ... ... ... 20/01/2016 4.3 3.2 0.3 1.3
... ... ... ... ... 19/01/2016 2.2 3.4 5.5 7.2
... ... ... ... ... 18/01/2016 4.4 2.3 3.4 5.01
```

The only information I have is that the data starts where `Timestamp` is located (could be anywhere in the excel sheet). And it appears in the format I presented here. 
I used two different approaches. From xlrd I have implemented the following code

```
 items = []
 for row in range(d_sheet.nrows):
     for col in range(d_sheet.nrows):
         items.append(d_sheet.cell(row,col))
 return items
```

and also using Pandas

```
 data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
 data.as_matrix()
```

In both cases, I end up with many blank lines with `NaN` values. 
I guess a simple solution is to run over the file and find the `Timestamp` element and print from that location into my file. But I was wondering if there is any other solution that identifies automatically where the data is printed in an excel sheet.

p.s. Ideally I would like to store data either in a DataFrame or dictionary format so I can use index and columns information in my code.

Comment: If there's a lot of NaN data in DataFrame, you can use `df.dropna()` as shown: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: That could be a solution but it will drop all `NaN` values that should appear inside my data, right? I mean what if I have some `NaN` values in my data (so important information).

Answer (score 1):

> In both cases, I end up with many blank lines with NaN values. I guess
>   a simple solution is to run over the file and find the Timestamp
>   element and print from that location into my file. But I was wondering
>   if there is any other solution that identifies automatically where the
>   data is printed in an excel sheet.

** a simple solution is to run over the file and find the Timestamp**

There is no other way out. If you do not have a fixed location for where the element timestamp begins, you need to run all over the file and find the element, even if you have a solution like - remove all NaN data from my xls - behind the courtain, this will run all over the file too.

Comment: Thanks Victor but what if that `NaN` is a value inside my data? this way I will ignore that value and indeed change the structure of data. I only need to extract the matrix whatever values they have (there could be `NaN` in my data as well).

Comment: Sorry man, I just made a confusion about your question. Im going to edit.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I was hoping to see some tools from Pandas or other library to import the data. But I guess, I need to do it manually. Cheers.

Comment: I am not python heavy user but I mean even if you use some pre-made solution, it will run in the same logic.